# Can i use jmonkeyengine on android?

Tags: java, android, 3d, jmonkeyengine

I'm, trying to make a simple 3D game for Android, and I want to use jmonkeyengine. Can I do this? How can I do it? Can somebody can show me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jME 3 can be used on Android, and the Android support is a relatively new feature as of 2011, but a previous version of jME cannot be used. Mostly this was due to architectural issues with an inflexible pipeline under the hood that wouldn't easily be able to support the mobile GL API.

---

Edited post because information was no longer accurate and was receving downvotes (cannot delete as it is the accepted answer).

Answer (score 48):

I'm a manager with the jMonkeyEngine project.

I apologize for the late response, but StackOverflow posts got such an excellent search ranking that people are still coming to our site via pages like this one, so I figured I'd best bring this topic up to speed.

In short, yes you can use jMonkeyEngine **3** on Android. Not the older 1.0 and 2.0 versions. However since jME3 is shader based it requires OpenGL 2 and above, meaning we can't support Android versions prior to 2.2 Froyo.

The [Android forum](https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/c/troubleshooting/android) is the best place to keep up to date on the latest development. We have a test application available on the market, for free of course. Testing is greatly appreciated! (Do note, while the tests have been reported to work fine for Motorolla and Samsung devices, as of writing they do not work yet for HTC phones. Expect a fix shortly).

On a last note, for anyone who thinks the jMonkeyEngine project has stagnated, I welcome you to visit our website and try the latest version of our SDK. Safe to say, the project is healthier than every before.