# Android 3D object with physics

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, 3d-engine

I've been an Android programmer for a while, but I've never touched 3D Graphics (OpenGL 2 ES).

To keep this question simple, this is along the lines of what I need to do...

A piece of material with texture, waving in the wind which I want to draw in a GLSurfaceView I want to be able to control the speed of the wind, but what would be really nice is to be able to move the material with touch. So a physics engine of some sorts will be involved.

This question is for experienced 3D graphics developers for android. How would you go about doing this, and what tools do I need?

Comment: Looks like there's a cloth plugin for Unity 3D: http://u3d.as/content/cloak-works/shroud-cloth-simulation-engine-android-/3aN

Comment: Not an experienced 3D graphics developer, but I know you can use [jMonkeyEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4789315/377628) with Android. This will allow you to keep everything in Java. It makes setting up a 3D scene really easy, and it has [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) built-in.

Comment: But won't I have to show Unity3D splash when using unity? I want to do this in 1 activity View.

Comment: Not sure - you'd have to google around to see your options.  However, I do believe it is highly likely that you will need a third party physics engine to pull off anything but the most rudimentary physics with a reasonable amount of effort.  And simulating cloth waving in the wind adds another level of difficulty that is probably pushing you to the cutting edge of mobile graphics capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 3d cloth simulation. From Blender Wiki:

> Cloth simulation is one of the hardest aspects of CG, because it is a
>   deceptively simple real-world item that is taken for granted, yet
>   actually has very complex internal and environmental interactions.
>   After years of development, Blender has a very robust cloth simulator
>   that is used to make clothing, flags, banners, and so on. Cloth
>   interacts with and is affected by other moving objects, the wind and
>   other forces, as well as a general aerodynamic model, all of which is
>   under your control.

See: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Physics/Cloth

There is an Android project on Google Code that implements a flag waving in the wind:

http://code.google.com/p/waving-flag-android/

I hope this helps you.